# Using iOS and Swift, how do I get the list of songs in a playlist in their natural order

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, playlist

I would like to display the list of songs in a playlist, in the order in which they were created.  The code below, returns the list in alphabetical order which I do not want.  Thanks in advance for any help you may have.  I am using Xcode 7.3.1.

```
var qrySongs = MPMediaQuery()
var selectedPlaylistTitle: String! // Set elsewhere in the code
let predicateByPlaylistName = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: selectedPlaylistTitle, forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)
qrySongs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
qrySongs.addFilterPredicate(predicateByPlaylistName)
```

Comment: I _think_ it's `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID`.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I'm not sure how I could use the idea though.  I know the selectedPlaylistTitle.  I could find the PersistentID of that playlist title, and use that in the existing MPMediaPropertyPredicate.  But I'm not sure why the result would be different.  Its like I have to sort the list in a different way.  Each song in the playlist has a PersistentID, but I can't sort them numerically.  I guess I'm surprised I'm currently being returned a list in alphabetic order.

Comment: I tried this: let predicateByPlaylistPersistentID = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: selectedPlaylistPersistentID), forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID), but it didn't work.

Comment: I meant: You have to sort it by `PersistentID` "manually". But I am not sure. Sorry for being mistakable.

Comment: No worries.  I really appreciate you trying.  The query provides a lot of stuff (song titles and song persistenIDs, etc).  I tried sorting it by persistentID and that didn't work.  Using the data from a loop that contains: print(qrySongs.collections![i].items[0].title) and print(qrySongs.collections![i].items[0].persistentID), sorting in accending or decending order doesn't work.  Its a complete mystery why the list is in alphabetic order.  A query of an album returns the names in the correct order as they are on the actual album.  Thanks for your time all the same.

Comment: I found out what the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.  The list is in the correct order.  It had to do with how I was filling my table after the query.  A debug loop containing: print(qrySongs.collections![i].items[0].title), produces an alphabetic list.  A debug loop containing: print(qrySongs.items![0].title), produces a list in the correct playlist order (as it appears in iTunes).  It is my use of collections! when I fill the cell, that causes the list to be alphabetic.  I will have to make the change in how I fill the cell.